# Pandas unicode issue with isin

Tags: python, unicode, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
      CONV_FIELD
0      u'Ignore'
1      u'Ignore'
2      u'Ignore'
3      u'Ignore'
4      u'Ignore'
5      u'Ignore'
6      u'Ignore'
7      u'Ignore'
8      u'Ignore'
9      u'Ignore'
10     u'Ignore'
11     u'Ignore'
12     u'Ignore'
13     u'Ignore'
14     u'Ignore'
15     u'Ignore'
16     u'Ignore'
17      u'Other'
```

I want to exclude all 'Ignore' from the data frame, so I do this:

```
df[~df.CONV_FIELD.isin([u'Ignore'])]
```

However, perhaps because all CONV_FIELD column values seem to be in unicode, this statement does nothing. How do i fix this?

P.S. There are other columns as well, and the dataframe is a lot bigger than shown..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a little odd that the `u'...'` actually shows up when you print your dataframe. It makes me suspect that you have strings that literally contain `u'Ignore'`. If I eval those strings, I just get `Ignore` when I print:

```
import ast
df['conv_field_fixed'] = df.CONV_FIELD.map(ast.literal_eval)
df
Out[13]: 
   CONV_FIELD conv_field_fixed
0   u'Ignore'           Ignore
1   u'Ignore'           Ignore
2   u'Ignore'           Ignore
3   u'Ignore'           Ignore
4   u'Ignore'           Ignore
5   u'Ignore'           Ignore
6   u'Ignore'           Ignore
7   u'Ignore'           Ignore
8   u'Ignore'           Ignore
9   u'Ignore'           Ignore
10  u'Ignore'           Ignore
11  u'Ignore'           Ignore
12  u'Ignore'           Ignore
13  u'Ignore'           Ignore
14  u'Ignore'           Ignore
15  u'Ignore'           Ignore
16  u'Ignore'           Ignore
17   u'Other'            Other

# If we look at the first item we see it is
# still a unicode string:
df.conv_field_fixed.iloc[0]
Out[15]: u'Ignore'
```

And now the subsetting operation works:

```
df[~df.conv_field_fixed.isin([u'Ignore'])]
Out[14]: 
   CONV_FIELD conv_field_fixed
17   u'Other'            Other
```

Comment: hmm, I am getting this error msg: *** IndentationError: unexpected indent (<unknown>, line 1) after df['conv_field_fixed'] = df.CONV_FIELD.map(ast.literal_eval)

Comment: My code here includes some output as well, you should only copy lines that look like Python expressions, not the `Out[14]:` lines or printed dataframes

Comment: It's also possible that your CONV_FIELD values contain leading tabs/spaces: you should try `repr(df.CONV_FIELD.iloc[0])` and closely inspect what is actually contained in those strings.

Comment: If there are leading spaces, something like `df['conv_field_fixed'] = df.CONV_FIELD.map(lambda s: ast.literal_eval(s.strip()))` should fix it.